# App is hanging during MagnificationGesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app is hanging during MagnificationGesture.onChanged.  I believe it is some sort of cycle between the scale and the GeometryReader above.  I read of a similar problem involving GeometryReader and preferencekeys:

> It sounds like you have a cycle in your updates. For example, a
> GeometryReader that writes a preference, that causes the containing
> view to resize, which causes the GeometryReader to write the
> preference again. It’s important to avoid creating such cycles. Often
> that can be done by moving the GeometryReader higher in the view
> hierarchy so that its size doesn’t change and it can communicate size
> to its subviews instead of using a preference. I’m afraid I can’t give
> any more specific guidance than that without seeing your code, but
> hopefully, that helps you track down the issue!

[SwiftUI | Warning: Bound preference _ tried to update multiple times per frame. Possible reasons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64941607/swiftui-warning-bound-preference-tried-to-update-multiple-times-per-frame)

I originally also had a preferenceKey and received the bound preference error, but the problem occurs without the preferenceKey.  The app is still running as indicated by the print statement, stuck in a loop of onChanged calls.

This occurs on iPad, but appears to not occur on Mac (Designed for iPad)

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var scale = CGFloat(1.0)
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    @State private var viewportBounds = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    
    private var mapSize: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: 1000 * scale, height: 1000 * scale)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            ZStack {
                Color.gray
                .frame(
                    minWidth: mapSize.width + (gp.size.width - viewportBounds.width),
                    minHeight: mapSize.height + (gp.size.height - viewportBounds.height))

                Color.red
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .gesture(
                    MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0.06)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        let delta = value / self.lastScale
                        self.lastScale = value
                        
                        let newScale = self.scale * delta
                        self.scale = min(3.0, max(newScale, 0.25))

                        print(self.scale)
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.lastScale = 1.0
                    }
                )
            }
            .frame(minWidth: gp.size.width * 0.75)
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:

This doesn't occur in the simulator or on the Mac.  But it does occur in iPadOS 15 on an actual device.  I rebooted the device to no avail.  Will try my iPhone and an iPadOS 14 device as soon as I can and will post an update.

FURTHER UPDATE:
This problem occurs also on an iPhone 8 Plus (actual device) running 15.3.1.  My iPad Pro running iPadOS 14.8.1 does not appear to suffer the problem. I used Xcode 3.2.1 for these and the problem persists across all my devices.

Comment: works fine in my Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution (I believe) to the problem.  I dispatch the change to scale to the main queue.  I figure this will assure that it only changes once per view update preventing the cycle.

I still don't understand why this is not a problem in the simulator or iOS 14.  I would love to hear from any better answers or insight into the problem.

```
MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0.1)
.onChanged { value in
    let delta = value / self.lastScale
    self.lastScale = value
    
    var newScale = self.scale * delta
    newScale = min(3.0, max(newScale, 0.25))

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        scale = newScale
    }
}
.onEnded { _ in
    self.lastScale = 1.0
}
```

This works on both iPadOS 15 and iPhoneOS 15.